# Windows GUI unresponsive under heavy load: Give it higher priority?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, high-cpu-usage, unresponsive

I'm doing some very heavy computation on a Windows Server 2012 machine. Like, thousands of processes doing heavy stuff.

Occasionally, I want to do some administration work and check progress. But the Windows GUI elements are all slow/unresponsive due to the load.

Is there a way to configure Windows to give higher priority to the GUI once it starts being used (ex: when moving the mouse)?

An alternative is to make something that programmatically lowers my program's thread priority. (Like, I can set all my worker threads to lowest priority.) But I'm curious if there's a simpler way.

Comment: No;  It sounds like you need more memory and to slower the priority of the process doing the computation itself.

Comment: You can also suspend the process that performs calculations and resume it later

Comment: Did you try by increasing the priority of Explorer.exe yet (via the Task Manager)?

Comment: Have you opened the *Performance Options* CPL applet and set best performance for *Programs*? Though this is not the normal setting for a server, it might be of help for your use. You might also eliminate all the special effects, such as animation, with that applet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set my process to use as many cores as the system has minus 1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1151879)

Comment: It answers the problem, which is that the GUI is unresponsive.  This will fix that problem.